# Get a string in text file by Line Number using Java?

Tags: java, string, text-files

I am having one text file like 1.txt

It contain some texts. Now i am have line number of above text file. Now i want string by line number in java..any one help me friends??

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/charstreams.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very basic method is to iterate the the file and return the line required as ,

```
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
for (int i = 0; i < lineNumber - 1; i++)
{
   r.readLine();
}
return r.readLine();
```

Remember Apache-commons provides the [`FileUtils.readLines(file).get(lineNumber);`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) method which accepts the input as `lineNumber` as the input to return the `String`

Comment: Thankyou..Now i am get the answer for both techniques..